# My http request block,what 's wrong?

Tags: http, blocking

[image]

I view my homepage in chrome, only one http request, and i encounter this case.

What 's wrong?

I can see that the dns not found when happened, so it's not a bug of server.

So  what chrome do at the moment.

Comment: One possible solution is that you issued too many simultaneous requests to the same domain and some of them are waiting for others to complete. That would be this blocking time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/speedtracer/MlF_gTvMRD8

> The 'Blocked' time is the delta between the 'requestTime' and the
>   'startTime'. Basically, this is a measure of the amount of time
>   between the UI thread initiating the request for the network resource
>   and the HTTP GET for the request bits getting onto the wire. In
>   between, there can be internal queuing/message passing delay, cache
>   lookup, dns resolution, and TCP connection setup.

Among the causes mentioned, it sounds like DNS lookup is the only one that would take that long. However it does look like the DNS lookup eventually succeeded, otherwise the whole request would have failed. Here's one possible cause of DNS delay: http://www.bigthinka.net/support/web-browsers/google-chrome-slow-dns-resolving.html

If that doesn't solve it. Try updating the question with more info about your DNS settings.